# Remove a broken Panel icon

Tags: icons, panel, notification-area

Today this "forbidden" ethernet/airplane mode icon appeared in the Panel.

[image: panel with indicator icons, one broken]

The little square one with the red circle. How do I remove it please? I've tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+right-click, but the only option not grayed out is **Always on top** which isn't much help.

Comment: That icon comes from an indicator/application that you've installed, and is having trouble finding its icon. Pull down a menu from that icon... using either left click, or right click, and identify which indicator/application it is. Then quit/exit it, and/or uninstall it.

Comment: there is no way to identify the program/indicator. Is there a way to list all the indicators in the top bar? I ran "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" but there is no easy way to indetify it.

Comment: Can anyone else help?

Comment: Although I don't have much info for you right now, it looks like you're running into this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-network/+bug/1649613

Comment: In `terminal`, type `dpkg -l *indicator* | grep ii` and that will give you a list of indicators that are installed. Match the list to what you see in the top panel. It won't show you applications, like **Skype**, that put up their own panel indicator. Are you running Skype?

Comment: Your broken app us where my battery icon usually resides I think (on my phone now)